# Get every line of a .txt file generated with PutAppend as an element of a list

Tags: import

I have filled a .txt file with expressions, separated by new lines, through PutAppend.

I want to define a list whose elements are those expressions. The first thing I tried was

```
list = Get[file.txt];
```

but the resulting expression is composed only by the first line of the file -- which was to be expected since the file is not written in Mathematica's list format.

Comment: Try `Import["file.txt", {"WL", "ExpressionList"}]`.

Comment: Are you sure that your `Get` command returns the first expression in the file? According to the docs, Get "reads in a file, evaluating each expression in it and **returning the last one.**"

Comment: @MarcoB You are absolutely right, sorry!

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Thank you for your suggestion! I get the following error '"The Import element \"\!\(\"WL\"\)\" is not present when importing as \
\!\(\"Text\"\)."'

Comment: Please shows us a few lines of the contents of the file you are trying to import. Even better, show an example of the `PutAppend` expression that generated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example:

```
expr1 = Sin[x];
expr2 = {{y[x] -> -(1/2) a E^-x (-1 + E^x Cos[x] - E^x Sin[x])}};
expr3 = FactorInteger[479001600];

PutAppend[expr1, expr2, expr3, "C:\\test.dat"]
```

creates a file with three expressions. In order to read this into a list:

```
alist = ReadList["C:\\test.dat"];
```

> ```
> {Sin[x], {{y[
>      x] -> -(1/2) a E^-x (-1 + E^x Cos[x] - E^x Sin[x])}}, {{2, 
>    10}, {3, 5}, {5, 2}, {7, 1}, {11, 1}}}
> ```

```
alist == {expr1, expr2, expr3}
```

> (* True *)